# How to check debug logs for a user for whom tracing is not set

Tags: apex, debugging, debug-logs

I need to check the debug logs when a user creates a case from the community. Obviously i will not be knowing which user will be creating a case in advance hence i cant set trace flag. How to check/set the logs in this case.

Comment: what's the root issue you are seeing that needs debugging (I'm assuming this is happening for authenticated community users as guest users can easily be debugged).

and if you login as that community user (from the Contact detail page - use Classic) - you can't repro the problem?

Comment: Yes, not able to reproduce.

Comment: In the absence of any other information, instrument the code path (case trigger, related object triggers, and log with platform events) until such time as problem recurs

Answer (score 0):

You only get logs for users that are being traced. You will need to know which user you need to trace. Debugging requires additional resources and will slow down the user experience.

Comment: Any possible way to handle this ? Issue in production which we're not able to reproduce in sandbox and also in production (when we try).